# Connecting to Localy hosted MAMP webserver on OS X

Tags: android, macos, webserver, localhost

I'm running an Apache and MySQL server on my MacBook for testing purposes and pursonal usage.
But when i try to connect via my Android phone, i get 'Connection Refused'

I am not surfing to localhost, but the local IP address of my macbook.

I've disabled my firewall (even if httpd,.. mamp services are allowed), same result
Changed port number, same result

I used to run a webserver on a Windows pc and raspberry pi, never had an issue, just browse to the IP address of the hosting device.. But it looks like OS X isn't allowing it

I've searched this forum a bit, but most problems were that people are browsing to localhost or trying to access it from outside the local network, couldn't really find a solution.

Step by step what i did: 
1. Started Apache & MySQL services 
2. Got the IP Address via ifconfig 
(0). Disabled Firewall
(0). Created a virtual host
3. Browsed to the IP on my Android

Comment: Can you get there from another device?

Comment: Also can't access it from another device

Comment: Also, I found this: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/131671/problem-accessing-localhost-on-mac-os-x-mavericks-it-was-working-fine-until-i

Not an answer, perhaps, but there are a bunch of helpful suggestions there.

Comment: I don't have an answer but I have MAMP working in my environment (so it is possible). Some suggestions: make sure your server started up (maybe there is a configuration error); try without virtual hosts (simplify your environment), see if can browse to it using macbook browser; make sure your Android WiFi is same subnet as macbook; make sure no htaccess file is preventing access; make sure listen port is as expected; try with httpd.conf <Directory> AllowOverride All for the document root; check the apache_error.log to see if something happened.  Good luck.

Comment: I've tried those things, still couldn't get it to work, even changed permissions and stuff.. nothing. Strange. But thanks for the suggestions ;) I'm just gonna use my Raspberry Pi whenever i want to test something over multiple devices. If i do find out what's the issue, i will post it here.